# Divergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

The sequence $(X_n)$ is said to diverge to $+\infty$ in probability if $\mathbb{P}\{X_n>b\}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ for every $b\in\mathbb{R}_+$. If  $(X_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$ in probability and $(Y_n)$ converges to $Y$ in probability ($X_n,Y_n,Y$ are real-valued random variables for all $n$), then $(X_n+Y_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$ in probability.

Can't seem to start on this one. I even have trouble showing that $\mathbb{P}\{X_n>b-Y\}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ for every $b\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For given $\epsilon>0$, fix  $K \in \mathbb{N}$, $K \geq 3$, such that

$$\mathbb{P}(|Y| \geq K \, b) \leq \epsilon.$$

By assumption, we can choose $N$ sufficiently large such that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( X_n \geq 2K\,b, |Y_n-Y| \leq \frac{K \,b}{2} \right) \geq 1-\epsilon$$

for all $n \geq N$. By the triangle inequality,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X_n+Y_n \geq b) &\geq \mathbb{P} \left( X_n \geq 2 K \, b, |Y_n-Y| \leq \frac{K\,b}{2}, |Y| \leq K \,b \right) \geq 1-2 \epsilon \end{align*}$$

for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Nope, I can't. The first term on the right tends to 1, the second to 0 and the last one is unclear (but non-negative). We conclude that the limit of the probabilities on the left is smaller that 1. Nothing new.

Comment: @nokiddn The last term was not unclear, but you are right, the estimate was the wrong way round. Should be fine now.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks.